# Сколько гласных и согласных звуков в пословицах?

Tags: фонетика

Сколько гласных и согласных звуков в пословицах:

Что посеешь, то и пожнёшь [што пас'эйэш' то и пажн'ош'] - 11 согласных, 8 гласных.

Что летом родится, то зимой пригодится [што л'этом рад'ица то зимой пр'игад'ица] - 17 согласных, 13 гласных.

Скромность каждому к лицу [скромнас'т' каждаму к л'ицу] - 14 согласных, 7 гласных.

Терпенье и труд всё перетрут [т'ирп'эн'йэ и труд вс'о п'ир'итрут] - 15 согласных, 9 гласных.

Comment: @elenaalisa, Предложите, пожалуйста, свой вариант ответа на данное задание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество правильное, а сама транскприпция неверна, если это не начальная школа.

Что посеешь, то и пожнёшь [што пас'эйьш /то ипажн'ош]-у шипящих нет мягкости, заударные гласные редуцированные.

Что летом родится, то зимой пригодится [што л'этъм рад'ица /то з'имой пр'игад'ицъ] .а ослабленная-крышечка

Скромность каждому к лицу [скромнас'т' каждъму кл'ицу].

Терпенье и труд всё перетрут [т'ирп'эн'йь итрут фс'о п'ьр'итрут]-и с призвуком э

Comment: Что посеешь, то и пожнёшь [што п^с'э'ṷьш/то ип^жн'ош]-11 согласных, 8 гласных.
Что летом родится, то зимой пригодится [што л'этъм рад'ица/то з'имой пр'иг^д'ицъ] -17 согласных, 13 гласных.
Скромность каждому к лицу  [скромнас'т' каждъму кл'ицу]-14 согласных, 7 гласных.
Терпенье и труд всё перетрут [т'иэрп'эн'йэ и труд вс'о п'ьр'иэтрут]-15 согласных, 9 гласных.

Comment: [т'иэрп'эн'йь-заударный, Ь-ерь